# Elasticsearch-rails How to increase accuracy in result as expected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch-rails

I am using elasticsearch-rails and elasticsearch-model gem for searching words in my rails app.

Here is my model **article.rb** where I want to search to take place:

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  settings index: { number_of_shards: 1 } do
    mappings dynamic: 'false' do
      indexes :title, analyzer: 'english', index_options: 'offsets'
      indexes :text, analyzer: 'english'
    end
  end

  def self.search(query)
    __elasticsearch__.search(
      {
        query: {
          multi_match: {
            query: query,
            fields: ['title^10', 'text']
          }
        },
        highlight: {
          pre_tags: ['<em>'],
          post_tags: ['</em>'],
          fields: {
            title: {},
            text: {}
          }
        }
      }
    )
  end
end

# Delete the previous articles index in Elasticsearch
Article.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.delete index: Article.index_name rescue nil

# Create the new index with the new mapping
Article.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.create \
  index: Article.index_name,
  body: { settings: Article.settings.to_hash, mappings: Article.mappings.to_hash }

# Index all article records from the DB to Elasticsearch
Article.import

#Article.import force: true
```

Here is my **search.html.erb**:

```
<h1>Articles Search</h1>

<%= form_for search_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label "Search for" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Go", name: nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<ul>
  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <li>
      <h3>
        <%= link_to article.try(:highlight).try(:title) ? article.highlight.title[0].html_safe : article.title,
          controller: "articles",
          action: "show",
          id: article._id%>
      </h3>
      <% if article.try(:highlight).try(:text) %>
        <% article.highlight.text.each do |snippet| %>
          <p><%= snippet.html_safe %>...</p>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Here is my **routes.rb**:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles
  get 'search', to: 'search#search'
end
```

Here is my **search_controller.rb**:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def search
    if params[:q].nil?
      @articles = []
    else
      @articles = Article.search params[:q]
    end
  end
end
```

Now, I am getting results only matching words.
My questions are:
How I can do composite matching?
I am not understood how this function works- 
and how to change queries??

```
 def self.search(query)
            __elasticsearch__.search(
              {
                query: {
                  multi_match: {
                    query: query,
                    fields: ['title^10', 'text']
                  }
                },
                highlight: {
                  pre_tags: ['<em>'],
                  post_tags: ['</em>'],
                  fields: {
                    title: {},
                    text: {}
                  }
                }
              }
            )
          end
        end
```

also How can I increase accuracy like composite match, spell check, partial matching? 
Thank You.